# How do I ignore warnings when running a jar?

Tags: java, batch-file, javafx, cmd, jar

So I run my jar using a batch script with the following line:

```
start "" "..\jdk-11.0.13.8-hotspot\bin\java.exe" -jar .\myjar.jar
```

Then I get the following output which I would like to ignore:

> ```
> Jan 24, 2022 1:04:57 PM javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement processValue
> WARNING: Loading FXML document with JavaFX API of version 17 by JavaFX runtime of version 11.0.2
> ```

P.S. I need to use Java 11 and I am not sure if switching to JavaFX 11 will cause issues. Everything seems to be working fine so I would like to just ignore this warning and that first line. I would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 2):

It should be sufficient to just change the version number in the header of your FXML file.

I am talking about a line similar to this one:

```
<VBox prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="640.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/17" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
```